# Rails find_by_sql - Use "?" literally rather than as bind variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In the below, I want the first `?` to be used literally, only the second `?` should be used as the bind variable marker:

```
Foo.find_by_sql ["select IFNULL(col,'?') from foos where id = ?",1]
```

This errors:

> wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2)

How would I escape the first `?` so it is treated literally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ActiveRecord isn't smart enough to ignore placeholders in string literals so it thinks that the `?` in `'?'` is a placeholder rather than part of a string. The easiest way around this is to use named placeholders:

```
Foo.find_by_sql ["select IFNULL(col, '?') from foos where id = :id", :id => 1]
```

When ActiveRecord sees a Hash in the array's second element it will look for named placeholders (which use Ruby symbol notation) rather than positional `?` placeholders. I tend to lean towards named placeholders period as they're more readable and more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass '?' as a param:

```
Foo.find_by_sql ["select IFNULL(col,?) from foos where id = ?",'?',1]
```